# return hTemp == ht2.hTemp;

Tags: java

Подскажите, что за такая конструкция `== ht2.hTemp` ? Нигде не могу найти описание.
Обычно сравниваются переменные таким образом `x == x`. Но в данном случае объект класса `ht2` и через точку имя переменной `hTemp`.

```
boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
    return hTemp == ht2.hTemp;
}
```

Comment: Очень похоже на ошибку

Answer (score 0):

```
ht2.hTemp
```

так получают значение публичного поля

Comment: Подскажите, где можно подробней прочесть об этом. В Шилдте не нашел пока еще. Спасибо!

Comment: поиск по ключевым словам `java модификаторы доступа`